# What kind of coordinate uses this WMS? Also how to convert to lat/lon

Tags: wms, coordinate-system

On this map http://infomapa.rosario.gov.ar/emapa/mapa.htm which I believe is MapServer, I get some coordinates after inspecting with Chrome like this:

```
    "geoJson" : "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[5433059.165834456,6360608.810436543]}"
}, {
    "numero" : 3004,
    "linea" : "106",
    "geoJson" : "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[5433151.161165902,6360413.851751617]}"
}, {
```

1 - How do I know which type of coordinate are these?

2 - How do I convert to lat, lon?

As an example I know:

```
   "geoJson" : "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[5434921.2799996715,6359301.360077026]}"
```

should be almost equal to this

```
-32.907269, -60.695515
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code of the application page shows that WMS layers are read with parameter "&SRS=EPSG:22185

A test with gdaltransform http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html gives support for this:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:22185 -t_srs epsg:4326
5434921.2799996715 6359301.360077026
-60.6956426930295 -32.9071417880402 0
```

Not quite same as your numbers but rather close. And you were right, it is MapServer of a somewhat old version 5.6.5.

Comment: It's very close, I took the lat/lon values myself , that's why they're not identical, Thanks for the accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably Argentina zone 5 which has a central meridian at 60W and uses transverse Mercator. The latitude of origin is at 90S, thus the large northing values. The false easting at the central meridian is 5500000 meters. Scale factor is 1.0.

The [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) has several zone 5 listed based on different geographic coordinate reference systems. For example, EPSG::5347 uses POSGAR 2007. You may need to do some digging to see if you can figure out which GeoCRS is being used.

I can't seem to get the WMS capabilities which would list the well-known IDs available, but I opened a PDF of the official city map and it listed POSGAR 94, fada (zone) 5. That's EPSG::22185.

Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that manages the EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry.

Comment: The page source code shows that WMS layers are read as EPSG:22185.